# How to install Prometheus node exporter on an already existing docker container?

Tags: docker, monitoring, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I have 3 nodes running in individual Docker containers and I want to monitor them using Prometheus. I have already deployed a docker container with Prometheus server, but node exporter needs to be installed in the containers to export metrics to the server. The containers are built using an Ubuntu image and a .jar is run in each container.

1. How can I install node exporter binary on the already running containers?
2. How to make sure that after a restart, node exporter is automatically installed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Prometheus node exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter) collects "hardware and OS metrics exposed by *NIX kernels".  Since all Docker containers on a given host share the same host kernel, it doesn't make sense to run this in every container.  Run it once, and given the nature of the stats it collects, run it directly on the host.  (Probes for things like device statistics, processes, and the state of the NTP daemon won't work well from inside a container.)

If you just want to monitor your applications, you need to add the [Prometheus Java library](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java) and have your application serve its data on `/metrics`.  You don't need the node exporter, and there's nothing Docker-specific about this setup.

As a general rule you never install anything in a running container, since it will get lost as soon as the container exits and is deleted (which is an extremely routine occurrence).  The general answer to "how do I install X in a container" is to add it to your image's `Dockerfile`, re-run `docker build` to rebuild the image, stop and delete your existing container, and re-run `docker run` against the new image.

Also as a general rule, running more than one process in a Docker container is discouraged: it adds significant complexity and operational difficulties.  (There's a quick-and-dirty way with a shell script, but you won't notice if one process or the other fails; there's a complex way involving something like supervisord, but it can hide process output and you might not be aware of serious trouble.)  If you did want to run the node exporter in Docker (with almost all of Docker's controls disabled) you'd generally run it in a separate container.